# Allow People to View/Edit Google Docs with a non-Google Account

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way I can allow someone who does not have a Google Account to view/edit my Google Docs?

Note that I am *not* saying I want to allow **everyone** to edit/view the documents. I want only to allow people with a certain non-Google email addresses to edit/view the documents.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually set view/edit permissions to any e-mail address by clicking the `Share`-button in the upper right but the persons who gets the permissions needs a Google account to use the document.

Comment: @eno, does this mean that I can only invite Google account to edit the document? Because if I invite a non-Google account, how does Google know what is his corresponding google account?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Google sends a link with an auth code. If you click on the link it asks you to log in (if you aren't). After you did this, the document is connected to your account (not sure whether it is possible to use this link again on another account).

Answer (score 5):

You can actually set view/edit permissions to any e-mail address by clicking the `Share`-button in the upper right but the persons who gets the permissions will have to create a new Google account or sign in with an existing Google account use the document.

Alternatively, you can set the document to be viewed and edited by anyone who has the link to the document (no sign-in required), email the link to the particular email address and request them to not share the link with anyone else.

You can see the screenshots below:

[image]

Then, Click on the "Change" button:

[image]

Now, select the setting as shown in this screen shot and click on "Save":

[image]

Now, Copy the links as shown in the screen shot below and share it with anyone you want through email. Do not forget to click on the "Done" button:

[image]

Comment: it looks like this has been changed and this answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 1):

If you set the sharing to "anyone with a link," then people can view or edit the document (depending on which you choose) without signing in to Google as long as they have the link. The only disadvantage, as far as I know, is that revision marking is less effective, because everyone is identified as "unknown." It is also somewhat less secure than the next option because the link could, in theory, get into the wrong hands,

If you restrict sharing to particular email addresses with "add people", they will need to either have or create a Google account to gain access. This is somewhat more secure. In addition, each revision will be associated with the person who made it.